# function that allows players of a html game to move pngs up and down a layer

Tags: html

i'm making a den designing game of sorts
but i can't find anything that would help me create a ui that can allow the player to move the desired png/pngs up and down a layer. So say the player has a "flower pot" and they want to move the png of the flower pot behind the png of the "bed". How can i create this function?
http://www.agame.com/game/My-New-Room
like in this game at the bottom
they have arrows that move the png up and down,
thank you for your help in advance!

https:// jsfiddle.net/okcjt5vf/294/ this is all my code so far.

Comment: Show us what you have tried?, if it's just css you can use `z-index` css property.

Comment: You could use `z-index` to achieve this. The function would take the element reference and adjust the z-index styling value based on the desired action (up/down)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/okcjt5vf/294/ this is all my code so far.

Answer (score 1):

Just a high level example:

This would, on click of an element with class `.adjustableElement`, cause the z-index to increase by one on the element.

```
$(".adjustableElement").click(function() {
    let newIndex = parseInt(this.css('z-index')) + 1;
    this.css('z-index', newIndex);
});
```

In your case, you will need to define a variable `selectedElement` to the png/image in question (However you decide this, by clicking on it etc.). Then, you will have two functions, one to raise one to lower depending on the arrow they action.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be working Dx

Comment: This is not going to just work if you drop it in. A lot is dependent on an implementation like this. You would have to make sure the positioned elements all have a valid z-index to start. may just set all to `900`. Also, you would have to ensure you build out the functionality needed for the selection of the actual element (`draggable` may hold onto this) as well as the arrows with appropriate functions.